# React-Native: How do I find file info for a ph:// uri?

Tags: react-native, photokit, camera-roll

I'm using the CameraRoll in React-Native 0.59.3 to fetch photos from the library.  I get back the following information:

```
height: 3024
isStored: true
playableDuration: 0
uri: "ph://CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3/L0/001"
width: 4032
```

How do I get the filename, filesize, mimetype, and normal URI from this information? What is the purpose of this new `ph://` uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you get those details successfully you can return promise to set the uri to your local state so you can use it.

something like:

```
this.setState({imageSrc: uri})
```

Comment: I don't need to display these images, I need to get the photo details (name, size, mimetype, etc) to send to the server. Once I have the uri - how do I get the rest of the photo details?

Comment: You can use this method to get the size of the image `Image.getSize(myUri, (width, height) => {this.setState({width, height})});`

Comment: Once you get the uri to your local state or prop you can fetch those with post request.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I could fetch one of those uris to get file info.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.

Comment: When I fetch from a "ph://" URI the response always lists the type as 'image/jpeg' regardless of if the media item is an image or video

Comment: Hey Adam, you can get media type of your response accordingly if you type `response.mediaType`